# Should the card board or just the card be statefull?

Tags: flutter

I have a board widget and a card widget.
The card model looks like this:

```
class Playcard {
  Playcard({
    required this.front,
    required this.back,
    required this.flipped,
  });

  final String front;
  final String back;
  bool flipped;
}
```

The board widget is showing the cards from the card widget.
The cards can be flipped. Initially all cards have flipped=false. When a card is flipped=true.
To show the card with the new value flipped=true should the board or the card be stateful?
I have created a card provider that sets the value of the card to true if it is flipped.

Comment: The ```Playcard``` widget has a flipped property that can change from *false* to *true*. This means that the ```Playcard``` widget should be a ```StatefulWidget```?

Answer (score 0):

you should change the value for `Card` Widget only rather than the whole `Board` Widget, to achieve the best performance and practice as well